# PHP issue with namespaces in index.php

Tags: php

trying to work something out.  I have my root folder which has index.php.  Inside this folder is another folder called classes.  Inside classes, I have three classes which have the namespace classes e.g.

```
<?php

namespace classes;

class MyClass {

...
```

Now back to index.php, this is not a class.  However, I need to use these classes in the classes folder.  I am trying without success

```
<?php

$reader = new \classes\MyClass();
```

With this I get the error that the class is not found.  I have also tried using a require, but because MyClass requires the use of another class in the folder, it means I have to require both classes to get it working.  So my only solution at the moment is

```
<?php

require_once('classes/MyClass.php');
require_once('classes/MySecondClass.php');

$reader = new \classes\MyClass();
```

For some reason I do not think this is the correct way to do it.  What is the appropriate way to use my classes in index.php?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). Ideally though, "MySecondClass.php" should itself be `require_once`'ing "MyClass.php", since it's derived from it and hence needs its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to work with namespaces you could use the PSR-4 convention and you could use the composer autoloader. Its very simple and you have a good structure.

http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/php-composer-autoloading/

Here is a good article that describes how to use the PSR-4 autoloader. It's the new way in working with Files and dependencies. And you have the ability to work with all other packages that use composer, too.

Comment: perfect, thanks.  Followed that guide and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use autoloader see [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md)
and [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)